# Hostname change error

Tags: 16.04, command-line, server

I have a user which belongs to sudo group. When trying to change hostname I am getting this error `mesg: ttyname failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device`
 and similarly when trying to reboot also am getting this

```
Failed to set wall message, ignoring: Interactive authentication required.
Failed to reboot system via logind: Interactive authentication required.
Failed to start reboot.target: Interactive authentication required.
See system logs and 'systemctl status reboot.target' for details.
```

Comment: did you `sudo `executed these commands?